# Webdriver: How to find the element using text() in xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm new to selenium and HTML. I want to perform click operation for the elements "Users" and "Admins" as one after another. Below mentioned is the HTML code, unfortunately I can't modify it.

```html
<ul id="nav">
<li class="">
    <a class="mainmenu" title="List of Users" menuid="nav_0">
        <span class="title">Users</span>
        <span class="arrow"/>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
            <a class="mainmenu" title="List of Admins" menuid="nav_0-sub_0">Admins</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="">
    <a class="mainmenu" title="List of Contents" menuid="nav_1">
        <span class="title">Contents</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="">
    <a class="mainmenu" title="Repos" menuid="nav_2">
        <span class="title">Repository</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I have used XPath like this:

```
.//*[@id='nav']/li[1]/a[contains(@title, 'List of Users']
```

Any other ways to get the element like matching the text value? Because the list elements order is dynamic, so the current position of the element "Users"(`li[1]`) might get change later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per given description, it seems that list of users will be maintained in HTML's List Item having common title=List of Users. So you can use something like below code to click on dynamic list items(here, users).

```java
List<WebElement> Userlist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[title='List of Users']");

for(WebElement ulist : Userlist)
{
    //Do your action, e.g. click() with each user name.
}
```

Comment: I find it hilarious that the accepted answer shows how to do it with a CSS locator when the OP explicitly asked for an XPath solution and there are valid XPath answers...

Answer (score 3):

You can try creating xpath with `text()` like these:

1. `//span[contains(text(),'Users')]`
2. `//span[contains(text(),'Contents')]`

Comment: It failed to pick element by using this.

Comment: Pankaj Kumar Katiyar/demouser123 is missing the closing bracket `]`.
`//span[contains(text(),'Users')]`
`//*[contains(text(),'Users')]`
`//span[text()='Users']`
`//*[text()='Users']`
`//a[contains(text(),'Admins')]`
`//*[contains(text(),'Admins')]`
`//a[text()='Admins']`
`//*[text()='Admins']`
any of these should work

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the `li[1]`, just use this XPath. It will still work, even if one of the `li` elements swap their locations in the html file.

```xpath
//*[@id='nav']/li/a[contains(@title,'List of Users')]
```

If you only have one `<a>` element on the page, you could avoid the `li` part

```xpath
//a[contains(@title,'List of Users')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```xpath
//*[@id='nav']/li[1]/a[contains(@title, 'List of Users']
```

You missed `)` at the last `]`, it should be like below:

```xpath
//*[@id='nav']/li[1]/a[contains(@title, 'List of Users')]
```